# To fill a dropdown from servelet using ajax

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I need to fill a drop down from database using ajax, Iam using two drop downs, if first drop down value is selected the second drop down value(have to be retrieved from DB based on the values selected in the first drop down) must have to be displayed. The DAO(Data Access Layer) returns 4 results as arraylist object but in http responsetext it is printing as object not the values.I tried using for loop to iterate it but i can't achieve it.  Please assist me on this.

**HTML Code:**

```
    // First Drop Down
    Question Field :<select name="ddlAddQuestionField" id='ddlAddQuestionField' onchange="getFieldPosition()">
        <option value=''>Select Question Field</option>
        <option value='Security Question'>Security Question</option>
        <option value='Personal Info'>Personal Info</option>
    </select>

    // Second DropDown

    User Field Position:<select name="userFieldPosition" id="userFieldPosition" disabled="disabled"> </select>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function getFieldPosition(){

                    var fieldName =$("#ddlAddQuestionField").val();

                    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

                        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                            document.getElementById("userFieldPosition").disabled=false;                            
                            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            var response =xmlhttp.responseText;

                            for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
                                var elements = "<option value='"+response[i]+"'>"+response[i]+"</option>";
                                $("#userFieldPosition").append(elements);
                            }
                        }
                      }
                        xmlhttp.open("POST","ApplicationController",true);
                        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        xmlhttp.send("fieldAction=fieldPosition&fieldName="+fieldName);
                }
```

**Servelet Code**

```
fieldPositionObj = fieldPositionDaoObj.getFieldPosition(fieldName);   //Hitting the Dao

              // In dao it returns arraylist object.     

            response.setContentType("text/plain");  
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
                response.getWriter().write(fieldPositionDaoObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is line

```
 response.getWriter().write(fieldPositionDaoObj);
```

You are writing java Obejct Directly on  Response.. I think `fieldPositionDaoObj` is list or aray.. so toString Representation is

```
(com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@23d275, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@1ce15f6, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@103fcaa, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@c135d6)
```

Where `com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@c135d6` is toString Representation of your Java Object.

I think wat you need to return there is **JSON** respresentation of Java Object/List/Array and your code will work

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), is a simple and easy to read and write data exchange format. It’s popular and implemented in countless projects worldwide, for those don’t like XML, JSON is a very good alternative solution.

Your JSON Representation should look like

> [ First,Middle,Full,Last]

or

> [{First},{Middle},{Full},{Last}]

you can write your  own method somethinglike `public String getJSOnRepresentation();`

and then do

```
response.getWriter().write(fieldPositionDaoObj.getJSOnRepresentation());
```

**[Sample example on What and how to code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)**

Also see

http://json.org/java/
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONString.java
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONArray.java
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();                                          String json = new Gson().toJson(fieldPositionObj); response.getWriter().write(json);          I tried this and i got  values but all the bean class properties are returned(in bean class i use too many properties all those properties are returned). I need only one property

Comment: Gson library can be found at http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ .. 
its smart library.. so its writing up all your values.. you can write your own implementation to write values needed by you

Comment: See updated answer (new links added)... If it helps please accept and upvote Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below mentioned code it's working fine now.

**JAVA SCRIPT:**

```
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("userFieldPosition").disabled=false;                            
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            elements  += "<option value='"+response[i].fieldPosition+"'>"+response[i].fieldPosition+"</option>";
        }
        $("#userFieldPosition").append(elements);
        }
}
```

**SERVELET:**

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = new Gson().toJson(fieldPositionObj);
 response.getWriter().print(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are certain frameworks such as ExtJs which allow you to do this with out much code. The only way I can think of doing this is by placing your second drop down box inside a `div` tag. On selection of the 1st drop down box, call a function which will make the ajax request. Once you obtain a `success` response, rewrite the content of your `div` by creating a new drop down box with these values.

Comment: Iam not getting the values iam getting only "(com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@23d275, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@1ce15f6, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@103fcaa, com.bean.QuestionInfoBean@c135d6)" this. (The exact values are First,Middle,Full,Last)

Comment: That's because you are writing the object directly. Check the values you are getting in the `ArrayList` using `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Also you aren't overriding the `toString()` of the `ArrayList`. The data what you get back might not be in the format required.

Comment: Use an ajax call. This is the easiest way to get data from a servlet.